# Расположение контента по вертикальной и горизонтальной середине

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

`section` должен доходить до конца окна браузера, а не ограничиваться своим контентом. После чего его контент должен быть по середине как и по горизонтали, так и по вертикали.

Код HTML

```
<section>
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <div>
        <div class="admin-block">
            <img src="img/admin_gallery.png" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="admin-block">
            <a href="?option=edit_users"><img src="img/admin_users.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <div>
        <div class="admin-block">
            <img src="img/admin_michail.png" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="admin-block">
            <a href="?option=edit_statii"><img src="img/admin_statii.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="admin-block">
            <img src="img/admin_weapon.png" alt="">
        </div>

        <div class="admin-block">
            <img src="img/admin_revard.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Код CSS

```
.admin-block { 
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Сейчас
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какой должен быть результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Полное интерактивное руководство по размещению в центре. Рассматривается несколько возможностей. При это не надо читать много буков, а достаточно выбрать свой случай. https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: Вам дали три ответа. Если какой-либо подошёл, то отметьте его как принятый. Если нет, то оставьте комментарий, что бы вам хотелось получить.

Comment: Картинки ставятся по вертикальной середине, но не по горизонтальной

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы `section` занимало всё окно экрана зададим ему высоту `100vh`.

Далее для расположения по центру и вертикально и горизонтально задаём `section` свойство `display: flex;` и его ребёнку `margin: auto;`.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

section > div {
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для родителя дивок:

```
   section>div{
        min-height: 100vh;
        display:flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.b {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #999;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.b-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;  
}
.b-items {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.b-item {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 48%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 1%;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.b-item:nth-of-type(odd){
  background: #F0FFFF;
 }
.b-item:before {
  content: 'icon';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: tomato;
  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="b">
  <div class="b-inner">
    <div class="b-items">
      <div class="b-item"></div>
      <div class="b-item"></div>
      <div class="b-item"></div>
      <div class="b-item"></div>
      <div class="b-item"></div>
      <div class="b-item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```